# python win32com how to set winhttp option value

Tags: python, win32com, winhttp

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

winhttp = Dispatch('winhttp.winhttprequest.5.1')

print winhttp.Option(6) #True

winhttp.Option(6) = False #SyntaxError  <----------------how to set Option(6) to false

print winhttp.Option(6)

winhttp.Open('GET', 'http://google.com', False)
winhttp.Send()

print winhttp.responsetext
```

> ===========================================
>
> output:
>
> invalid syntax: winhttp.py, line 13, pos 11 File
>   "c:\Users\***\Desktop\winhttp.py", line 13, in ?   set
>   winhttp.Option(6) = False
>
> how to do it? many thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why your question is being downvoted. I found it really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
winhttp.SetOption(6, False)
```

Unless you have some really good reason for using winhttprequest, I'd use something out of the Python standard library, or better yet install the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library.  You will find these options much easier to deal with.