# How to get JSON into Pandas dataframe with windows authentication

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to read json from intranet site that's using windows authentication  into pandas dataframe using read_json function but I'm getting 401 error.

A bit of googling showed that a similar issue with postman reading windows authenticated json was solved using Fiddler's "Automatically Authorize" function but it doesn't seem to work with pandas using anaconda.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json(windows authenticated url)
```

btw the url works just fine it returns a perfectly formatted json in browser.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give an accessible url example?

Comment: What do you mean by an accessible url? It's just a url like e.g "intranetsitecom/mydata" . it returns json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to do a HTTP GET request first using the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) package. The package provides a `get()` method that allows [authentication](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/#basic-authentication) as well as a [`json()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) method that returns the json-encoded content of a response. A code example could look like this:

```
import requests    

r = requests.get('https://intranet.jsondata.com/xy.json', auth=('user', 'pass'))
json_content = r.json()
```

Comment: it seems like it still can't authenticate and a bit of googling suggests I might have to use requests_nltm. Another issue is that I don't really want to put my username and password on a jupyter notebook. I'll give it a try with nltm library. thanks

Comment: update: I was able to get it to work with requests_nltm library but now the issue is how to convert that into pandas dataframe?

Comment: Do you use this package https://github.com/requests/requests-ntlm? Then you should be able to make a GET request for your json file and read the response into pandas (like in your OP). Do you get errors?

Comment: yes reading the response directly into read_json throws an error and even if I use  response.json() and then send it to read_json it still throws an error.

Comment: update: actually just passing it to pd.DataFrame(response.json()) worked. Thank you.

Comment: It would be nice to actually not put my credentials on jupyter since that's actually the whole point of windows authentication..This works but if you know of a way to avoid this that would be nice

Comment: Different approaches are discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44960472/storing-passwords-in-jupyter-notebooks

Answer (score 1):

- Is the URL on your corporate intranet?
- Do you normally enter it in the browser, then it pauses for a 10 .sec and you get the results without any password prompts?

  If the above is true, it probably uses Kerberos authentication.  You can certainly get it using  python.  Use here is the package that will help you with this https://github.com/requests/requests-kerberos

  Note, some language environments maintain their own HTTP/Kerberos stack ( Java ) so you need to log in into Active Directory Domain there separately from your OS login.

Comment: yes to both of your questions but I just tested an intranet url with fiddler and it seems we're using NLTMSSP. It doesn't really take 10 seconds though as it's pretty much instant. Is there a library for nltm?

Comment: There is NTLM requests library https://github.com/requests/requests-ntlm .  I am surprised you are using NTLM in 2018.  It's really not secure these days.

Comment: The reason it works seamlessly with fiddler, is because fiddler is probably uses WinHTTP library under the wraps.  That library is tightly integrated with the OS, so it inherits all windows authentication mecahnisms

Comment: Also you can use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417539/python-win32com-how-to-set-winhttp-option-value  technique to use WinHTTP from python.  You'll loose all the goodies provided by `requests` library,  but will get the seamless authentication